# Win Phone 8 WP8 Creating Dynamic Controls at runtime

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to be able to create dynamic controls at runtime - textblocks, buttons to be specific. I have tried this:
dim b as button = new button
b.content="test"

The code does not error but also does not produce a button either. Simple I know but for Wp8 it's quite difficult for me.
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Creating controls from code behind is usually not the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to add the button to your page. Try this:

**Xaml**

```
<ContentControl x:Name="container">

</ContentControl>
```

**Code**

```
Dim b as New Button With { .Content = "test"}
container.Content = b
```

Comment: Thank you thats great. I tried to add a click handler: AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf b_click which calls the method   Private Sub b_click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked" + sender.ToString + e.ToString)
    End Sub but it didn't fire the click method.